# Why it still access the row with state is deleted and got the error

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I got this error "Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row" even though the row is marded as deleted in the datatable b "buildinggroup" and I have the where statement of !(b.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted || b.RowState == DataRowState.Detached), but it still tired to access the deleted row and give the error. Not sure what is wrong. If I do acceptchanges before this, the changes won't get saved in the database.

```
 private ObservableCollection<ValueGroupData> GetValueGroupSource()
 {
       if (VisData.DbData.Tables.Contains("constr") && 
       VisData.DbData.Tables.Contains("valuebuilding"))
        {
            var list = (from DataRow c in VisData.DbData.Tables["constr"].Rows
                join DataRow v in VisData.DbData.Tables["valuebuilding"].Rows
                    on c.Field<decimal>("CNS_BID") equals v.Field<decimal>("VBD_BID")
                    join DataRow b in VisData.DbData.Tables["buildinggroup"].Rows
                        on v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_GROUP_ID") equals b.Field<decimal>("BGP_GROUP_ID")
                where ( !(c.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted || c.RowState == DataRowState.Detached)
                       && !(v.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted || v.RowState == DataRowState.Detached)
                       && !(b.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted || b.RowState == DataRowState.Detached)
                       && v.Field<decimal>("VBD_PID") == VisData.PID
                       && b.Field<string>("BGP_GROUP_NAME")== GroupName)
                select new ValueGroupData()
                {
                    VBD_BID = v.Field<decimal>("VBD_BID"),
                    VBD_BLDG_NUM = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_BLDG_NUM"),
                    VBD_ISPRIMARY = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_ISPRIMARY"),
                    CNS_STYLE = c.Field<string>("CNS_STYLE"),
                    CNS_STYLE_DESC = c.Field<string>("CNS_STYLE_DESC"),
                    VBD_LIVING_GBA = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_LIVING_GBA").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_RES_UNITS = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_RES_UNITS").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_COMM_UNITS = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_COMM_UNITS").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG_PCT = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG_PCT").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG_VAL = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG_VAL").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG") == 1,
                    VBD_IS_OVR_LAND_PCT = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_LAND_PCT").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_LAND_VAL = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_LAND_VAL").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_LAND = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_LAND") == 1,
                    VBD_IS_OVR_OB_PCT = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_OB_PCT").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_OB_VAL = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_OB_VAL").GetValueOrDefault(),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_OB = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_OB") == 1,
                    ValueGroupTotal = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_BLDG_VAL") + 
                                      v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_LAND_VAL") + v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_OB_VAL"),
                    VBD_IS_OVR_XF_VAL = v.Field<decimal?>("VBD_IS_OVR_XF_VAL").GetValueOrDefault(),

                }).ToList();
```

Comment: I suspect it's because the join will be performed before the where and will attempt to access info on deleted rows. I'd be interested to know if a construct like `from DataRow c in VisData.DbData.Tables["constr"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r.RowState != RowState.Deleted)` works (don't forgot to do it to the other tables too)- you could then remove your where clause calling for the same. By the way, I don't think a DataTable ever does contain a row with a RowState of detached; that's the state of a row that is not housed in a DataTable. Let me know if it works and I'll post it as an answer

Comment: You could also iterate the original table looking for rows in the deleted state, send those updates to the db (call someAdapter.Update(the deleted row) and call AcceptChanges on the row, to remove it from the table, before you query. Be wary of calling GetChanges(deleted) as this will return you a clone that is harder to integrate back